# Both radio buttons getting checked while using vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, radio-button, frontend, vuetify.js

I am creating all the generic used components like Inputs etc using vuetify and resuing them in a project but radio button behavior is not what I want both of them are getting checked instead of one and is not functional too

I've tried normal input tag without the vuetify v-radio component and it works fine but vuetify radio button is not working

Parent component

```
<c-radio name="radio1" v-model="radois" :value="defaultShift"></c-radio>
```

and in data property i have

```
      radois: null,
      defaultShift: 0,
      nightShift: 1
```

Child Component

```
<div>
 <v-radio-group>
   <input type="radio" :name="name" v-model="values" :value="value" @change="inputChange" />
   <!-- <v-radio :name="name" :value="value" @change="inputChange" /> -->
 </v-radio-group>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
model: {
 prop: 'values',
 event: 'change'
},
data() {
 return {
   radio: null,
   radioValue: this.label
 }
},
props: {
 // label: String,
 // label: String,
 value: Number,
 values: Number,
 name: String
},
methods: {
 inputChange(e) {
   console.log(e.target.value)
   this.$emit('change', event.target.value)
 }
}
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Expected Results are one of them getting checked when clicked and having clicked value and vice versa but rather both of them are getting checked and throwing undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because each child component creates separate v-radio-group. if you create a separate component for v-radio-group and use it as a wrapper on your child component then it should work.

example.

MyRadioGroup.vue

```
<template>
  <v-radio-group> <!--also props for these if required-->
  </v-radio-group>
</template>
```

MyRadio.vue

```
<template>
  <v-radio :name="name" :value="value" @change="inputChange" />
</template>
```

Now you can use these as below

```
<MyRadioGroup>
  <MyRadio></MyRadio>
  <MyRadio></MyRadio>
  <MyRadio></MyRadio>
</MyRadioGroup>
```